# Publish dependencies of an artifact with Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm looking for a way with Gradle to generate a maven repository with all dependencies and transitive dependencies.

For example, my project can depend on hibernate. I'd like to create a local repository somewhere on the disk with hibernate and its own dependencies.

I tryed several ways but no success:

- uploadArtifact: it seems not possible to upload dependencies of the artifact
- Sync task: I don't have maven metadata and I loose transitive dependencies

The context:
My product has an engine and a webapp and could deployed as a War archive, an EAR archive or without the webapp, with or without some components in them. I need to provide users a way to configure what they need and a script to generate it. Gradle seems a good candidate but I don't see how to create a local repository with all dependencies that may be needed.

Does anyone see a solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which may be used by others.
The idea: use maven to generate the repository and package the project as a zip using the assembly plugin.
I fake maven with :

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-internal-site</id>
        <url>file://${user.home}/.m2/repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and call it like it :

```
mvn install -Dmaven.repo.local=./src/lib/
```

The pom will contain main dependencies and src dir everything else to include in the "bundle"

Answer (score 2):

There isn't currently an easy way to achieve this with Gradle; you'll have to script your own solution. In particular, you'll have to find a way to recreate the original POM when publishing the archive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Peter, I was afraid of this answer. I'll check if I can use maven and the dependency plugin to generate the dependencies repository, or maybe write a Gradle plugin to achieve that.